# UItextView Justify Paragraph in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitextview, text-justify

I want to justify a paragraph using `UITextView` in an iPhone using xCode.

What property should I change to do this.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photo says it all. You could use the `Alignment` control to left, center or right justify text.

By the way this is got when you go to Interface builder, select that `UItextView` & then set these properties...

From code you could do - `[yourTextView setTextAlignment:<#(UITextAlignment)#>`

[image]

Comment: thanx for your concern. But I want to justify the paragraph(check this image) http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/word2007_2010/images/clipart/justify.gif

Comment: I want to make paragraph like this. http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/11-typography-on-the-web/02-rivers.gif

Comment: in iOS for `UITextView` you have only 3 ways to align text as far as i know. Not sure what the 4th is? is it Microsoft word?

Comment: yes it is ms word image which for explain my requirement :) 
check second image it shows the way I want to display my paragraph!

Comment: try the default text alignment iOS supports, maybe that will suffice? If there's no support,what can one do... Not sure you would want to go down the road to do your own layout handling for UITextView...

Answer (score 0):

The correct way To justify a paragraphy is:

```
    YOURTEXTVIEW.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
```