# How to set different margins for each line of an UITextView?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a UITextView that the user is going to complete. Something like this:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
    _ _ _ _ _
```

Those dashes are an image behind the textview. Each character has to be placed over each dash.

In the first line the user will be able to write only 9 characteres, then I'll add a breakline.
In the second line there are only 5 characters, but I want to add margin or padding, so it looks like the drawing. And I need to use only one text view.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995903/uitextview-justify-paragraph-in-iphone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246260/display-paragraphs-in-uitextview-without-n

Comment: I don't need to justify my paragraph, I just need to give a different margin to each line. If I center the textview, the first character will be in the center of the line, and it should be located over the first dash (left). The problem is with the 2nd line.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990173/indent-second-line-of-uilabel