# Indent second line of UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

So I have a UILabel that may or may not go to a second line, depending if it is on iPhone or iPad. What I would like to accomplish is to have it indent on the second line to line up correctly, if needed.

On iPad it will almost never need the second line break, and depending on which iPhone it is running on, it may or may not. So, in essence, I need a way to dynamically indent the second line, only when there is a second line.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use an `NSAttributedString` for your label, and set the [`headIndent`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSParagraphStyle/headIndent) of its [paragraph style](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/#//apple_ref/c/data/NSParagraphStyleAttributeName):

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
style.headIndent = 14;
NSDictionary *attributes = @{
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style
};
NSAttributedString *richText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"So this UILabel walks into a bar…" attributes:attributes];
self.narrowLabel.attributedText = richText;
self.wideLabel.attributedText = richText;
```

Result:

[image: example result]

Comment: I have a problem while using custom font. Do you also have a problem?